# VMware ESXi on Fujitsu Primergy RX300 S6

Tags: esxi

I want to buy a new Server:

*Fujitsu Primergy RX300 S6*

I want to install ESXi on it and I'm not sure I need to note something when installing it. Can I just install it like I would install Ubuntu on my old Server (Just an old PC), or are there some things to pay attention? Sry if that is a dumb question but I think there are sometimes custom Images for this kind of Servers.

I hope someone can help me there. Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English....

Comment: Buying recommendations are not allowed here

Comment: I don't really wanted to get a buying recommendation, but I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago i had to setup an "Fujitsu Primergy RX300 S6" with ESXi. So the Server is not exactly new. Back then (4-5 years ago). It run perfectly well and without any issues at all.

However i highly recommend to upgrade the servers BIOS and IO-Cards to the latest available firmware before installing ESXi.

Also it's possible that vSphere 6 support was dropped for the RX300 S6.

Double check your vendor support when updating ESXi hosts from VMware vSphere 5.5 to 6.0. There are a lot of systems that are no longer supported. The following servers were supported in 5.5 U2 but are according to the VMware HCL no longer supported in vSphere 6.0.

[Primergy RX300 S6 - Intel Xeon 55xx Series](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=server&productid=14511)
[Primergy RX300 S6 - Intel Xeon 56xx Series](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=server&productid=13900)